# Open Cover Balls in Analytic Theorem

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, number-theory

I am having trouble to understand the definition of cover, sub-cover and compactness which I find in the definition of analytic theorem (used for prime number theorem). Can anyone help me understand those three definition according to diagram used in analytic theorem given below?

[image]

To be precise, where are the line segment $L$ in the picture, and where are those open cover balls?

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence defines $L$ to be the set of complex numbers with magnitude no larger than $R$ which have zero real part (so they lie on the y-axis). In other words, it's the line segment between $-Ri$ and $Ri$.

Oddly, the *drawing* shows this as the *horizontal* axis, because the lines $t=\pm R$ are shown as *vertical* lines (note $t= \operatorname{Im} s$, so one would expect these to be horizontal lines with constant imaginary part). The balls covering $L$ are shown in the drawing as the disks along the horizontal axis between $t=-R$ and $t=R$ .

So either the drawing is wrong (probable), or the description is wrong (possible), or the drawing has an unorthodox orientation of the axes (doubtful).

---

**The take-away:** In the drawing, $L$ is supposed to be the line segment along the x-axis, and the small balls shown are the finite subcover of $L$ chosen from some arbitrary open cover. $L$ is the horizontal diameter of the circle of radius $R$. As I mentioned, the drawing and the description don't match up.

Comment: and where are those open cover balls? Can you upload a picture marking $L$?

Comment: In the drawing, $L$ is supposed to be the line segment along the x-axis, and the small balls shown are the finite subcover of $L$ chosen from some arbitrary open cover. $L$ is the horizontal diameter of the circle of radius $R$. As I mentioned, the drawing and the description don't match up. But the intent is clear, isn't it? I've added this to my answer.

Comment: Its anightmare who just started to study,it would be better if u upload a picture editing the existing picture according to description.

Comment: According to description, the union of those disks are open ball, not the disks themselves, right? Your answer is not clear without picture, also if u think $L$ is not defined properly as per diagram provided, you should provide the definition of $L$ in mathematical set terms.

Comment: Text says for each point $z\in L$ you can choose an open ball $U_z$ with $z\in U_z$ (on which $g$ is analytic, but that’s just a way to come up with some open ball for each point). This collection $\mathscr U$ of balls of course covers $L$ because every point $z$ of $L$ is in at least one of them, namely $U_z$; formally $$L=\bigcup_{z\in L}\{z\}\subseteq\bigcup_{z\in L}U_z=\bigcup\mathscr U.$$Since $L$ is compact, you can choose a finite subcover (definition of compactness), a finite number of balls from $\mathscr U$ that also covers $L$. Those are the small open balls shown.

Comment: Which point does $\sigma = 0$  indicate on the picture?

Comment: Thats not a point, it’s a line. That’s the horizontal axis (note the label on the lower right side directly above the line. Apparently in this drawing, the real axis is vertical and the imaginary axis is horizontal (!). In that case, $L$ is indeed the horizontal segment along the line $\sigma=0$ between $\pm iR$, the two endpoints where the horizontal axis meets the dashed vertical lines $t=\pm R$.